# OpenAPI spec using allOf to override inherited property

Tags: jsonschema, openapi, json-schema-validator

I am attempting to run an existing OpenAPI schema through [Open API Enforcer](https://byu-oit.github.io/openapi-enforcer/) and I am getting various validation errors in the usage of allOf.  One such usage is described below:

Consider the following property in a schema:

```
queryVersion:
    allOf:
      - $ref: 'VersionDefinition.yaml'
      - description: >-
          This is my overriding version
```

VersionDefinition.yaml is defined as follows:

```
description: >-
  Some default version description.
type: string
default: '5.2'
```

There are two issues with the above definition:

1. OpenAPI Enforcer expects all schemas defined within allOf or similar keyword to start with a type definition.  So, the error it spits out is:

   at: queryVersion > allOf > 1
               Missing required property: type

I fix that by modifying the allOf definition as follows:

```
 queryVersion:
    allOf:
    - $ref: 'VersionDefinition.yaml'
    - type : object
      properties:
      - description: >- 
           This is my overriding version
```

That eliminates the error but what should I expect to see in the generated schema?  Original author indicates he is using allOf to override the property description.  However, the generated schema includes this result:

```
                "queryVersion": {
                    "allOf": [
                      {
                        "description": "Some default version description",
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": "5.2"
                      },
                      {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": [
                          {
                            "description": "This is my overriding version"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
```

What I expected to see was:

```
      "queryVersion": {
                        "description": "This is my overriding version",
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": "5.2"
                      }
```

I'll keep digging but any ideas?

Comment: Your fix for the `allOf` error went too far. The `description` should not be under `properties` but on the same level as `type` and that `type` should also be of value `string` to be consistent

Comment: Makes sense.  I'll give that a shot, thank you.

Comment: Your original example is syntactically valid. OpenAPI Enforcer seems to be too strict. As to whether this approach will actually override the `description` - the result of having duplicate keywords in `allOf` subschemas may vary depending on the tool. Your original example works at least in Swagger UI.

Comment: While it is strict, it appears to one of the more solid validators, which is why I am hoping to stick with it.  But agreed.